# How to perform one hot encoding without converting a data frame into an array?

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have `df` data frame with categorical features columns `'temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse', 'mucous_membrane'`.
I want to encode categorical features like here:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
categorical_features = ['temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse', 'mucous_membrane']
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features)], remainder='passthrough')
df = ct.fit_transform(df)
```

But without converting the data frame to an array.

I've tried to apply that method:

```
categorical_features = ['temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse', 'mucous_membrane']
for feature in categorical_features:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df[feature], prefix=feature, dtype='int')], axis=1)
    df = df.drop([feature], axis=1)
```

However, that's not the correct solution because when applying this method to another data frame with the same features, the encoding is different

Comment: Can you give us an example of input data and matching output you want to have? In other words can you provide a [example]?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `scikit-learn` version `1.2.0` or later you can use the `set_output` method to return a `pandas.DataFrame` instead of an array.

---

## Example

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np  # 1.26.2
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


# For repeatability
np.random.seed(0)

# Setting some temporary defaults so I don't have to type out the parameters each time.
choice = partial(np.random.choice, size=(10,), replace=True)

# Make some fake data.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "temp_of_extremities": choice(a=["high", "low", "neutral"]),
        "peripheral_pulse": choice(a=[True, False]),
        "mucous_membrane": choice(a=[True, False]),
    }
)

# Initial setup from your question.
categorical_features = ['temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse', 'mucous_membrane']
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    # I set the `sparse_output` to False otherwise this will raise a ValueError.
    transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False), categorical_features)],
    remainder='passthrough',
    # Use the `set_output` method here to return a `pd.DataFrame` instead of a `np.ndarray`.
).set_output(transform="pandas")
out = ct.fit_transform(df)

print(out)
```

```
   encoder__temp_of_extremities_high  ...  encoder__mucous_membrane_True
0                                1.0  ...                            0.0
1                                0.0  ...                            0.0
2                                1.0  ...                            1.0
3                                0.0  ...                            0.0
4                                0.0  ...                            1.0
5                                0.0  ...                            0.0
6                                1.0  ...                            1.0
7                                0.0  ...                            0.0
8                                1.0  ...                            0.0
9                                1.0  ...                            1.0
```

To clean up the column names a bit, we can set `verbose_feature_names_out=False` in the `ColumnTransformer`.

```py
# Initial setup from your question.
categorical_features = ['temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse', 'mucous_membrane']
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    # I set the `sparse_output` to False otherwise this will raise a ValueError.
    transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False), categorical_features)],
    remainder='passthrough',
    # Set `verbose_feature_names_out=False` to keep original names + their encoded value.
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
    # Use the `set_output` method here to return a `pd.DataFrame` instead of a `np.ndarray`.
).set_output(transform="pandas")
out = ct.fit_transform(df)

print(out)
```

```
   temp_of_extremities_high  ...  mucous_membrane_True
0                       1.0  ...                   0.0
1                       0.0  ...                   0.0
2                       1.0  ...                   1.0
3                       0.0  ...                   0.0
4                       0.0  ...                   1.0
5                       0.0  ...                   0.0
6                       1.0  ...                   1.0
7                       0.0  ...                   0.0
8                       1.0  ...                   0.0
9                       1.0  ...                   1.0
```

---

## Resources

- [SLEP018: Pandas Output for Transformers with set_output](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep018/proposal.html)
- [Introducing the `set_output` API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html)